# javascript function instance has wrong its var

Tags: javascript, function, properties, instance

```
function myClass( _num) {
    var num;
    this.num = _num;

    var myFunction = function( ) {
        console.log("num", _num);
    }
    myFunction();

    myClass.prototype.fun = function( ) {
        myFunction();
    }
}

var c1 = new myClass(1);
var c2 = new myClass(2);
var c3 = new myClass(3);

c1.fun();
```

[code fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSpz8/169/)

I made my some wrong code simply.
I though that each function instance has their own property, so last console output would be `'num 1'` but `'num 3'`.

Am I thinking wrong way?

Comment: You are always assigning `4`, how can you expect 1 or 3?

Comment: sorry, I didn't update code on fiddle. could you review?

Comment: what is Num 1 or Num 3 ? you script does not contain those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
myClass.prototype.fun = function( ) {
    myFunction();
}
```

You are not assigning a function to the actual instance but to the class. Each time you instantiate the class, you are updating that prototype function that belongs to all instances to be the particular `myFunction` created during the the last instance.

You would get the desired behaviour with the following code:

```
this.fun = function( ) {
    myFunction();
}
```